# Debian Scripting to remove the logging during apt-get install

Tags: linux, debian, installation, script

I'm trying to remove the log that debian puts out after you apt-get install something

```
Ign http://ftp.uk.debian.org jessie InRelease
Hit http://ftp.uk.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease
Get:1 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease [63.1 kB]
Hit http://ftp.uk.debian.org jessie Release.gpg
Hit http://ftp.uk.debian.org jessie-updates/main Sources
Get:2 http://ftp.uk.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex [3,472 B]
Get:3 http://ftp.uk.debian.org jessie-updates/main Translation-en/DiffIndex [1,720 B]
Hit http://ftp.uk.debian.org jessie Release
Get:4 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Sources [131 kB]
Hit http://ftp.uk.debian.org jessie/main Sources
Hit http://ftp.uk.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://ftp.uk.debian.org jessie/main Translation-en
Get:5 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages [237 kB]
Get:6 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Translation-en [129 kB]
Fetched 565 kB in 3s (158 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libio-socket-ip-perl
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove it.
Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I want to remove this. Is there anyway to stop this whilst scripting?

Comment: Show the command you are executing - in particular, are you using the `-q` flag to `apt-get`?

Comment: what does the -q do?

Comment: Exactly as it says in the man page - *"Quiet; produces output suitable for logging, omitting progress indicators. More q's will produce more quiet up to a maximum of 2. "*.  You did read the man page before asking, I hope?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redirect the `stdout` to `/dev/null` by appending `> /dev/null` to any command:

```
apt-get update > /dev/null
```

To also redirect `stderr` to `/dev/null` append `2>&1`:

```
apt-get update > /dev/null 2>&1
```

To upgrade or install packages without being prompted for `[Y/n]` add `-y`:

```
apt-get upgrade -y > /dev/null 2>&1
apt-get install <package> -y > /dev/null 2>&1
```

You could also send it to a log file:

```
apt-get upgrade -y > script.log 2>&1
```

A single `>` will overwrite the file, to log multiple commands use two `>>`, which will cause the output to be appended to the end of the file:

```
apt-get update >> script.log 2>&1
apt-get upgrade -y >> script.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Also if i'm installing multiple things into the same log file will this work?

Comment: Happy I helped. See my uptaded answer.